# How to launch Windows 10 Mail app in specific folder?

Tags: email, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

What possibilities are there to launch the Windows 10 mail app in a specific folder, from another app?

Background: say I am programming a UWP app allowing the user to select a folder in one of his mailboxes (however I'll be doing this). Now I want to open the standard Windows 10 mail app *showing exactly this folder* (identified by name, by ID, by whatever).

Can this be done? How (URI scheme, ...)? (Please focus on the Windows 10 mail app part. Identifying the folder in the first place is another problem to be solved.)

Sample workflow for the user:

- Open my app and see a list of his email folders (Inbox, Personal, Work, TODO, etc.)
- Tap one folder name
- Standard Email app opens, shows emails of the selected folder (<- this is what this question is about)

Comment: I am not too clear what effect you really want to do. Do you mean to launch the mail app meanwhile the mail app display a specific folder such as inbox or Send Items?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT I added a sample workflow hopefully making it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function can not be implemented in UWP app. In UWP, it only exposed a [mailto: URI scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app#email-uri-scheme) to launch the default mail app, we can not navigate to the specific page of the Mail app from your UWP app.

Comment: I am trying to similarly open the mail app to a specific folder within a specific logged in account. Is this answer still true? I posted a separate question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689854/how-to-open-email-app-to-specific-folder-powershell